# Does the order of CSS gradient definitions matter?

Tags: css

I've been reading a lot about CSS3 gradients recently, and I'm curious about whether the order of the vendor-prefixed definitions matters or not. For example, I see a lot of the following:

```
background: #0A284B;
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#0A284B),
                                                            to(#135887));
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#0A284B, #135887);
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #0A284B, #135887);
background: -ms-linear-gradient(#0A284B, #135887);
background: -o-linear-gradient(#0A284B, #135887);
background: linear-gradient(#0A284B, #135887);
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient
        (startColorstr='#0A284B', endColorstr='#135887');
```

However, I also sometimes see examples of CSS gradient definitions where the filter declaration is towards the top, or others that also include the -ms-filter prefix, etc., etc.

So I guess my questions are these:

- Does the order of the definitions matter?
- Should I be using the -ms-filter prefix?

As far as I can tell, so long as the regular background declaration is first and the W3C-official linear-gradient is last, it doesn't matter.

I should note that I focused on linear gradients above, but I think the same question applies to radial gradients as well.

Comment: Order of prefixes *can* matter depending on the property/values.  Some versions of Opera (Presto) have aliased the webkit prefixed properties to either their own prefixed property or the standard property, depending on which one Opera supports.  I've read that Firefox mobile does the same as well (can't find source for this), but not the desktop version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When dealing with prefixed CSS, the defined correct answer is always put the prefixed versions first, followed by the un-prefixed version.

So `-webkit-whatever` and `-moz-whatever` must come before plain old `whatever`, and the plain unprefixed version must be specified (even if it isn't supported by any browsers yet).

This is important because the last defined version that is recognised by the browser is the one that is used, and it is preferable for the browser to use the un-prefixed "standard" version if it understands it.

Above the un-prefixed version, the order of individual prefixed versions like `-moz-`, `-webkit-`, etc is generally unimportant -- any given browser **should** only ever recognise one of them, so it doesn't matter what other they're in. A common answer to this is to put them in length order, because it looks neat, but it doesn't actually matter.

I emphasised "should" in the above paragraph because there are a few cases where some browsers (eg Opera) implemented `-webkit-` prefixes even though they had their own `-o-` prefix. This was because people weren't using the `-o-` prefix, and they felt that they were losing out on functionality in some sites even though their browser did actually support it. For this reason, I'd prefer to have `-webkit-` defined first, so that in cases where this is being done, the browser's own native prefix can take precedence.

Regarding styles where old IE uses a `filter` or `-ms-filter` style instead of the standard, this again doesn't matter, because if IE uses the filter it should not be using the standard CSS.

Even if IE does recognise both the `filter` and the standard CSS, it still doesn't matter about the order, because they are seen as separate styles. The point of putting the CSS in a particular order would be to get the browser to pick one over the other, but `filter` does not override `background`, nor is it overridden by it, even if they are doing the same thing, so it's irrelevant.

There are a few cases where these can clash -- eg doing rotation using `-ms-filter` and standard `transform:rotate()` together will result in IE9 doing *both*, and thus make a mess of things. IE<=8 only knows `-ms-filter` and IE10 doesn't support `-ms-filter` at all, so it's only IE9 that is affected, but it's a nasty one because there isn't a way to avoid it in pure CSS. One has to resort to either browser-specific code or CSS hacks or polyfill scripts. But this point doesn't apply to gradients because IE9 doesn't support the CSS standard.

Comment: In the case of gradients, supporting the webkit prefix became a necessity since many authors fail to provide a background-color as well.  If the text color is set to white and the parent element is white, then there's a usability problem.

Comment: @cimmanon: Yep. CSS Prefixes... sigh. The whole concept can be summarised with the saying "the road to hell is paved with good intentions".

Comment: Great answer, Spudley. Thanks a lot. Also, thanks for the additional comment, cimmanon. I guess the conclusion is that for gradients, the -webkit prefixes should come first, with the -webkit-gradient one coming before -webkit-linear-gradient (because -webkit-gradient is older), and then organizing the other prefixes from longest to shortest. Lastly, filter and -ms-filter can be added wherever in relation to background-image because they won't override each other. Thanks.